# Empty white rectangle in the new design

Tags: bug, status-completed

I really love the new design! I think there is a bug or something missing. I have an empty white rectangle on the sidebar on the right. I've tried without an ad-blocker and with different browsers but nothing makes it disappear.

Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: I now realize it's probably for the community ads...

Comment: No white block in my world...

Comment: Correct, or rather for the "Beta-Ads". If I interpret my console correctly, this probably got blocked with a mixed-content warning. HTTPS-Everywhere can cause this

Comment: Yeah, gonna need to fix that mixed content warning. Good news - not a design problem. I'll take a look in a while here.

Comment: @AdamLear i thought it's actually because of AdBlock..?

Comment: @Paweł Nah, I can reproduce without AdBlock.

Comment: The problem here is in Adzerk (or possibly in our usage of it). The ads team is gone for the weekend now, so I'll have to follow up on Monday.

Comment: No problem ! Thanks for the update!

Comment: Today again I see the [empty white rectangle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FVMg7.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had to tweak the URLs used to request these ads internally. They are now protocol-relative, so you should see the question and proposal ads show up fine over HTTPS now.